# Migración Wordpress problema de redirección

Tags: wordpress

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tenia un sitio web montado en **godaddy.com**,
hice una migración desde ahí hacia un nuevo hosting con nuevo dominio.
los pasos a seguir fueron :

1. Mediante FTP descargar todo el contenido de la carpeta public html.
2. Exportar la BDD.
3. Subir el contenido a la nueva public html.
4. Crear una nueva base de datos y usuario, asociarlos e importar la BDD.
5. Usar la herramienta "https://interconnectit.com" (También probe con los comandos SQL y los plugins de search and replace)
6. Actualice en enlaces permanentes desde la administración de wordpress.

Aun así desde la barra de navegación me sigue redigiriendo al dominio anterior, funcionando bien solo el home.
(la redirección del menu es del tipo oldsite.com/page en vez de newsite.com/page)

He probado miles de soluciones sin resultado.

Hay una sola solución que no he probado porque el hosting nuevo no me permite el acceso al archivo **httpd.conf**.
Encontrada en :
" https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14685/after-server-migration-only-the-homepage-works "

Necesito de su sabiduría querida comunidad.

**Solución : 
Se debio cambiar manualmente las redirecciones en los archivos footer.php y header.php**

PD :Gracias a todos.

Comment: Hay dos parámetros en la base de datos relacionadas con el dominio de tu sitio, no mencionas haberlos cambiado (a menos que eso haga la herramientas que mencionas). Tampoco haces mención de cambios en `.htaccess`. Por favor indica claramente qué has intentado por _miles de soluciones_ es demasiado. Aclara tu pregunta agregando los datos faltantes. Usa este enlace: [edit].

Comment: No mencionas si en la tabla `wp_..._options` modificaste el valor de la columna `option_name` correspondiente a `siteurl`. Allí debes poner el nombre del nuevo dominio: `http://www.nuevo-dominio.com`. No creo que debas modificar el `httpd.conf` ya que estás en un nuevo hosting, el cual no tenía ni idea de tu antigua configuración. A lo sumo, si has migrado tu archivo `.htaccess` debes verificarlo, no sea que contenga redirecciones basadas en el anterior dominio.

Comment: Buenas, ¿has podido realizar la migracion correctamente? ¿Te sirvió la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Generalmente es el proceso que suelo utilizar yo tambien. Posibles cosas que debes de revisar:

- Lo primero es comprobar que en la base de datos ya no queda nada con la URL anterior, entiendo que con `Search & Replace` has cambiado todo `http://oldomain.com` por `http://newdomain.com`. Si no queda nada de la URL antigua vamos bien.
- Tienes que verificar que no tienes ningún plugin de caché que pueda estar haciendo de las suyas, en caso de que sea así borra el caché o directamente desactiva el plugin
- Si tenias algun plugin de seguridad tipo `iThemes` o `Wordfence` revisa que en su configuración no tengas algo forzado, aunque `Search & Replace` toque toda la BBDD, esos plugin generan `.htaccess` en varios directorios.
- Verifica que tu `.htaccess` no tenga nada del antiguo dominio. Si tienes acceso SSH a tu directorio lo puedes hacer usando esto: `egrep -r 'oldomain.com' *`
- Por ultimo, intenta entrar a la página en modo "incógnito" del navegador, si por alguna cosa estabas haciendo redirecciones 301, el navegador puede haberlas cacheado y llevándote a confusión.
- Como te comentan por aquí, puedes comprobar las DNS (por si fuera el problema) de que estén apuntando al antiguo servidor y que estes cargando otra página web, aquí tienes un par de herramientas: https://www.dnswatch.info/ y https://www.whatsmydns.net/

Si todo esto que te he comentado no soluciona el problema, tendrás que mirar el error log del sistema y comentarnos algo.